# How to apply Animate.css effect to the element ONLY when scrolled to it?

Tags: javascript, css, effects, animate.css

Am using animate.css library to apply animated effect on my website. But the problem is effect is applied as soon as page is loaded. And when I scroll to the element effect is already applied. 
How can I set effect to be applied only when the element appear while scrolling?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Waypoints – A javascript library that allows you to execute a function when you scroll to an element.

The basic Waypoint function in jQuery looks like this:

```
$("#element-to-animate").waypoint(function() {
    // animation code
  }
}, { offset: '100%'});
```

The 'offset' value determines at what point the animation is triggered. 
[Here](http://imakewebthings.com/waypoints/guides/getting-started/) is the guide to setting up and using waypoints.

Answer (score 2):

You need to add `wow.js` and apply it. This will work when you scroll down to bottom.
To use it, add wow.js in head and add the `wow` class in the animated element.

```
<div class="FadeIn wow">
  ------
</div>
```

[Get it Here](http://mynameismatthieu.com/WOW/). and read full documentation.