# Animate.css: trigger animation when becoming visible while scrolling

Tags: css, animate.css

I'm experimenting with animate.css.

My code:

```
<h2 class="lazyload animate__animated animate__rotateInDownLeft" data-link="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/animate.css/4.1.1/animate.min.css">Lorem ipsum</h2>
```

Please, don't be afraid of animate.css being loadeded lazily here.

My page: https://galina.xyz/makiyazh/oshibki-pri-makiyazh

We are interested in the bottommost h2 with the text "Lorem ipsum".

**The problem**

This works perfectly when I reload the screen with the h2. That is when it is already visible.

But what I'm looking for is an animation effect while scrolling. That is the H2 should start moving only when it has been scrolled to.

Is it possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@Mohammed animate-dynamic solution use jQuery.

This one instead is a simple solution in vanilla JS using [Animate.css](https://github.com/animate-css/animate.css), [Waypoints](https://github.com/imakewebthings/waypoints) and a few lines of css:

javascript:

```js
//https://stackoverflow.com/a/74810616/3929620
//https://stackoverflow.com/a/32677672/3929620
//https://stackoverflow.com/a/69614783/3929620
const animateList = [].slice.call(document.querySelectorAll('.__animate__animated'))
animateList.map(function (animateEl) {
    new Waypoint({
        element: animateEl,
        offset: 'bottom-in-view',
        handler: function(direction) {
            //https://stackoverflow.com/a/56914528/3929620
            animateEl.className = animateEl.className.replace(/__animate__/g, 'animate__')
            this.destroy()
        },
    })
})
```

css:

```css
/* https://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#attribute-substrings */
[class*="__animate__"] {
    opacity: 0;
}
```

html:

```html
<div class="__animate__animated __animate__fadeIn">
    <!-- your code here -->
</div>
```

Any improvement is welcome! ;)

Answer (score -1):

Seems like animate.css doesn't provide the animate on scroll functionality, which usually needs javascript. So you are better off adding your own `window.scroll` event, which checks if your `h2` becomes visible in the the viewport then add class `animate__rotateInDownLeft`.

Answer (score -1):

There is no such feature in animate.css library, you need to use javascript/Jquery to do some tweaks and tricks and get what you want.

I am working on such library from few days, and managed to somehow make a stable library.

visit [animate-dynamic.ga](https://kodingkhurram.github.io/animate.css-dynamic.demo/)

Github [animate-dynamic](https://github.com/KodingKhurram/animate.css-dynamic)

For any queries comment down.

For any difficulties with library feel free to create issue.

Comment: Bro, remove jQuery please! https://medium.com/@apoorva72900/why-is-jquery-dead-b41dba56491e

Comment: @Frugan yes, [v3.0.0](https://github.com/KodingKhurram/animate.css-dynamic/releases/tag/v3.0.0) now it's purely JS library.